# How to mutate data in SWR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I have two functions. The first one gets the data and returns all quotes, mutation function, and loading boolean.

```
// Fetcher and the baseUrl
export const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';
export const fetcher = (arg: any, ...args: any) => fetch(arg, ...args).then(res => res.json());




//get completed quotes
export const getAllQuotesArray = () => {
    const { data: allQuotes, isLoading: allQuotesLoading, mutate: mutateAllQuotes } = 
    useSWR(`${baseURL}/get-quotes`, fetcher);

    return { allQuotes, allQuotesLoading, mutateAllQuotes };
}
```

The second function deletes an record and return the remaining array of objects (same in the API route).

```
//get completed quotes
export const getCompletedQuotes = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}get-completed-quotes`, {
            method: 'GET'
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('', error);        
    }
}



export const deleteFromCompletedQuotes = async (quoteId: string) => {
    try {
        await fetch(`${baseURL}delete-quote?id=${quoteId}`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        });
        const allRemainingCompletedQuotes = await getCompletedQuotes();

        //re run the function
        getAllQuotesArray();

        //return an array of objects
        return allRemainingCompletedQuotes.completedQuotes;
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('', error);        
    }
}
```

How can I revalidate the data in the `deleteFromCompletedQuotes` function?
I tried to mutate alot of times... But it won't work. The reason for my approach is because I have two components in my page where one displays completed quotes and other all the quotes. But If i delete one of the record, in the second div no change will happen...

Answer (score 0):

`getAllQuotesArray()` returns `{ allQuotes, allQuotesLoading, mutateAllQuotes }`. you can use `mutateAllQuotes` mutator inside `deleteFromCompletedQuotes`

export const deleteFromCompletedQuotes = async (quoteId: string) => {
try {
await fetch(`${baseURL}delete-quote?id=${quoteId}`, {
method: 'DELETE'
});
const allRemainingCompletedQuotes = await getCompletedQuotes();

```
    //re run the function
    const {mutateAllQuotes}=getAllQuotesArray();
    // it's argument must be the data that you returned in the first place, which is all quotes
    // now you need to pass allRemainingQuptes
    mutateAllQuotes(allRemainingCompletedQuotes)

    //return an array of objects
    return allRemainingCompletedQuotes.completedQuotes;
    
} catch (error) {
    console.log('', error);        
}
```

}